# Как правильно пишется "детский мир"?

Tags: орфография

"Детский мир" уже давно перестал быть названием магазина, а стал, скорее, его определением, как "гастроном" или "универмаг". Но как его правильно писать? В кавычках или без? Со строчной или с прописной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правы в том, что название де-факто уже превратилось в имя нарицательное. Ну или нечленимый оборот. Но поскольку словарями пока не фиксируется, писать следует в соответствии с общими рекомендациями. 
"Детский мир".
Подробности - см. у Людмилы.

Answer (score 2):

Детский магазин или магазин детских товаров - не название, а "Детский мир"-название, потому что это метафора, метафора всегда индивидуальна, хотя и становится общепринятой.Хотя когда-нибудь,возможно, не будет восприниматься как метафора,но пока, думаю, рановато.

Answer (score 1):

В советские времена, когда монополизм процветал, магазины "Детский мир" были синонимом магазинов детских товаров. Как, например, программа "Время" - синоним теленовостей.

Сейчас "Детский мир" - это всего лишь одна из нескольких крупных сетей по продаже детских товаров. Но привычка в народе осталась. Так, у нас в городе в старом "Детском мире" сейчас мебельный магазин, со своим названием. Но люди всё равно говорят: "Мы в детском мире диван заказали".

Comment: Вы правильно сказали: говорят, но писать следует"Детский мир", потому что имеется в виду магазин, который когда-то имел такое НАЗВАНИЕ.

Comment: да, пожалуй, так